# AzureDevops passing $`` instead of $() into jq arg via taskgroup

Tags: azure-devops, jq

I currently have the following in my taskgroup bash script

```
jq --argjson timestamp "$`date +%s`" '.common |= . + {"TimeValue": $timestamp }' ${service}/${env}.json > tmpfile && mv tmpfile ${service}/${env}.json
```

my issue is with this part

```
"$`date +%s`"
```

when the task runs I get the following error

```
jq: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson
Use jq --help for help with command-line options,
```

So if I edit the existing release and change it to the following everything works:

```
"$(date +%s)"
```

The problem is when I change to the above in my taskgroup it now thinks that I am trying to add a new parameter which I do not want.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I guess issue is that you should have ```"`date +%s`"``` instead of ```"$`date +%s`"```

Comment: That was the fix!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change to like as one of the below ways.

```bash
jq --argjson timestamp `date +%s` '.common |= . + {"TimeValue": $timestamp }' ${service}/${env}.json > tmpfile && mv tmpfile ${service}/${env}.json
```

OR

```bash
timestamp=`date +%s`
jq --argjson timestamp $timestamp '.common |= . + {"TimeValue": $timestamp }' ${service}/${env}.json > tmpfile && mv tmpfile ${service}/${env}.json
```

Comment: It's safe to remove the quotes here (as long as the value of IFS isn't wacky), but the general solution would be to use `"\`cmd\`"` instead of `"$\`cmd\`"`